# How do I create a new pandas DataFrame containing specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame containing values for `Year` and `Month` (represented as integers) like this:

```
df.head(5)
    Year    Month   
0   1997    1   
1   1997    8
2   2010    9
3   1998    1
4   2009    10
```

> I want to create a new DataFrame containing only year values 1996, 2000, 2002

I hardly ever use python or pandas so I'm stuggling here, I tried:

`df2 = df.ix[df.year = 1996 and df.year = 2000 and df.year = 2002 ['year', 'month']]`

but this doesn't work - could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin` and pass your list to filter the df:

```
In [168]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':np.arange(1997,2010), 'Month':np.arange(13)})
df[df['Year'].isin([1996, 2000, 2002])]

Out[168]:
   Month  Year
3      3  2000
5      5  2002
```

What you tried fails because `and` doesn't understand array like comparisons, you need to use bitwise `&` and wrap the conditions in parentheses:

```
df2 = df.ix[(df.year == 1996) & (df.year == 2000) & (df.year == 2002)]
```

Additionally `=` is assignment which is not the same as equality `==`